# Change Collection Propery When Nested Collection Property Changes

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Full solution: https://github.com/fallingsappy/portfolio/tree/master/DDrop

I have three collections. First one:

```
public class Series : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<DropPhoto> _dropPhotosSeries;
    public ObservableCollection<DropPhoto> DropPhotosSeries
    {
        get
        {
            return _dropPhotosSeries;
        }
        set
        {
            _dropPhotosSeries = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DropPhotosSeries"));
        }
    }
    private bool _canDrawPlot;
    public bool CanDrawPlot
    {
        get
        {
            return _dropPhotosSeries?.Where(x => x.Drop.RadiusInMeters != null).ToList().Count > 1 && _dropPhotosSeries?.Where(x => x.Drop.RadiusInMeters == null).ToList().Count == 0;
        }
        set
        {
            _canDrawPlot = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CanDrawPlot"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

Second:

```
public class DropPhoto : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Drop _drop;
    public Drop Drop
    {
        get
        {
            return _drop;
        }
        set
        {
            _drop = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Drop"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

Last:

```
public class Drop : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double? _radiusInMeters;
    public double? RadiusInMeters
    {
        get
        {
            return _radiusInMeters;
        }
        set
        {
            _radiusInMeters = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RadiusInMeters"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

I want to update (invoke?) property CanDrawPlot every time something is happens to two other collection (Drop and DropPhot.cs). For example, if `DropPhotosSeries.Count` goes lower then 2 I need to change CanDrawPlot to false. CanDrawPlot should update UI. Here is the XAML:

```
                <TabItem IsEnabled="{Binding CurrentSeries.CanDrawPlot, ElementName=AppMainWindow,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="SingleSeriesPlotTabItem" Header="График" >
                    <uc:ScatterPlot x:Name="SingleSeriesPlot" User="{Binding User, ElementName=AppMainWindow}" ParticularSeriesIndex="{Binding ParticularSeriesIndex, ElementName=AppMainWindow}"/>
                </TabItem>
```

CurrentSeries is instantiated in MainWindowXaml.cs:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentSeriesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentSeries", typeof(Series), typeof(MainWindow));
public Series CurrentSeries
{
    get { return (Series)GetValue(CurrentSeriesProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(CurrentSeriesProperty, value);
    }
}
```

---------------UPDATE---------------

I changed my code accordingly to Rob's answer:

```
public class Series : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Series()
    {
        _dropPhotosSeries = new ObservableCollection<DropPhoto>();
        _dropPhotosSeries.CollectionChanged += _dropPhotosSeries_CollectionChanged;
    }
     private void _dropPhotosSeries_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CanDrawPlot)));
    }

    private bool _canDrawPlot;
    public bool CanDrawPlot
    {
        get
        {
            return _dropPhotosSeries?.Where(x => x.Drop.RadiusInMeters != null).ToList().Count > 1 && _dropPhotosSeries?.Where(x => x.Drop.RadiusInMeters == null).ToList().Count == 0;
        }
        set
        {
            _canDrawPlot = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CanDrawPlot"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

Now CanDrawPlot correctly notifies changes in DropPhoto Collection. But I need to invoke it also by changes in inner Drop class of DropPhotoSeries. Here what i did:

```
public class Drop : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Series _series;
    public Drop(Series series)
    {
        _series = series;
    }

    private double? _radiusInMeters;
    public double? RadiusInMeters
    {
        get
        {
            return _radiusInMeters;
        }
        set
        {
            _radiusInMeters = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(_series)));
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RadiusInMeters"));
        }
    }
}
```

its not working, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hook up to CollectionChanged event of the ObservableCollection and in there you have to raise PropertyChanged for CanDrawPlot.

EXAMPLE:

Add constructor to the Series class and in the constructor instantiate the observable collection and subscribe to the CollectionChanged event.

```
public Series()
{
    _dropPhotosSeries = new ObservableCollection<DropPhoto>();
    _dropPhotosSeries.CollectionChanged += _dropPhotosSeries_CollectionChanged;
}

private void _dropPhotosSeries_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CanDrawPlot)));
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample? I don't realy understand how to do it.

Comment: that worked just fine. But what if i want CanDrawPlot to be invoked when RadiusInMeters of Drop class changes??

Comment: Than you need to pass the instance of the Series class to constructor of the Drop class and in setter of RadiusInMeters you would call OnPropertyChanged of Series instance.

Comment: I've updated my original question according to you answer, could you check, what is wrong now?

Comment: You need to call _series.OnPropertyCHanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Series.canDrawPlot))); Also, I suggest you read up a bit on how INotifyPropertyChanged interface should be consumed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, i think i missing on some knowledge of that. I will read more. But for now you solution works great.